# academic and calendar years

Tags: usage

In English it's fine to talk about this/last/next "year" even when referring to academic/fiscal as opposed to calendar years. Does this work for Japanese too? For example, in March does it make sense to say, 「来年もよろしくおねがいします」? Or 「来学年もよろしくおねがいします」?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

When referring to academic/fiscal year, you use [年度]{ねんど}, as in:

> [来年度]{らいねんど}もよろしくおねがいします。

Comment: As a side note, "this academic/fiscal year" and "last academic/fiscal year" would be [本年度]{ほんねんど} (or [今年度]{こんねんど}) and [昨年度]{さくねんど} (not 去年度), respectively. [前年度]{ぜんねんど} and [次年度]{じねんど} would be "the previous academic/fiscal year" and "the next academic/fiscal year" respectively.

Answer (score 5):

来年 is totally fine, especially in this personal/friendly situation. A more specific term is "年度" (as in 来年度もよろしくお願いします). 年度 is a general term for a year, starting at convenient date for each context, like academic/fiscal/whatever year. As both academic and fiscal year start at April in Japan, you can usually interpret plain "年度" as a April-March period given no context.

So when you need to be clear or in formal contexts, use 年度. Otherwise 年 is just fine.

Comment: 学年 is more like grade as in third-grader, by the way.